# Making a servlet "Public"?

Tags: xpages

I finally got my test servlet working from this thread?

[Calling HttpServlet class from xpages client side script and regular notes forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226268/calling-httpservlet-class-from-xpages-client-side-script-and-regular-notes-forms)

The issue that remains is I am being asked to login. But my final servlet will need to run without logging in.  I have my acl set to Read public document and Write public documents for anonymous.

What I don't know how to do is to make the serlet public access.   Other design documents have an "Available to Public Access users" property but I am seeing no such property for java files.  Would this be set somewhere else?  Maybe in my IServletFactory perhaps?

Comment: Well it looks like it is not done in the IServletFactory because it looks like it is not called till you login so I am guessing the factory class would need to be "public" too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I was required to log in before but it looks like it is now working.  The only thing that is requred is that Read Public Public Document be enabled.

This is a bit concerning since it at least appears there is no way to make some servlets non-public.  In my case it won't be an issue but it could be an issue for others.

Also what I noticed is that if you change the Public Access acl setting, it looks like you need to rebuild your servlets for some reason or the servlets won't run.  When I get a chance I will open a ticket with notes support for both of these issues.

For those wanting to execute a servlet, I suggest this article:

http://8b30b0.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/creating-a-basic-domino-servlet/#comments

But here is a much more simplifed version of IServletFactory  that might be easier to understand and get working.

```
package test;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule;
import com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.IServletFactory;
import com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ServletMatch;

public class TestFactory implements IServletFactory {

private ComponentModule module;

public ServletMatch getServletMatch(String contextPath, String path)
        throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("TestFactory:getServletMatch");

    String servletPath = "";
    String pathInfo = path;
    return new ServletMatch(getWidgetServlet(),servletPath,pathInfo);        
} 

public void init(ComponentModule arg0) {
    System.out.println("TestFactory:init");
    this.module = arg0;
}

public Servlet getWidgetServlet() throws ServletException {
    return module.createServlet("com.pnc.cld.HelloWorld", "testServlet",null);
 } 

}
```